# Cuando al app se queda en suspenso mucho tiempo despues no arranca, swift xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

Estoy desarrollando una app en **swift** y **Xcode**, utilizo **Core Data**.

Ya en pruebas, cuando dejo la app en segundo plano normalmente no pasa nada pero en ocasiones (mucho tiempo inactiva: 18 - 24 horas) ya no arranca ni la app en segundo plano ni arrancándola otra vez.

En el **viewWillDisappear** lo que hago es guardar los datos que aún no se han guardado de la partida actual.

Nota: mientras ha estado la app en segundo plano prácticamente el iPhone no ha hecho nada, por lo que en **didReceiveMemoryWarning** no debería pasar aunque también guardo los datos en juego.

En realidad no sé qué hacer en **viewWillDisappear**

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad lo que pasa es que una vez instalada la App en un dispositivo real (desde Xcode) para pruebas, al cabo del tiempo (una semana, más o menos), "caducan" las credenciales de esa App en tu terminal y ya ni arranca, por lo que tienes que volver a instalarla desde Xcode.
Espero que sirva.